# Find an orthogonal matrix $V$ such that $V^{T}B(\gamma)V=diag(1+\gamma n,1,1,\cdots,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

> Let $B(\gamma)=I+\gamma ee^{T}$ where $e=(1,1,\cdots,1)^{T}$ and $\gamma$ a strictly positive real number.
>
> I would like to find an orthogonal matrix $V$ such that $V^{T}B(\gamma)V=diag(1+\gamma n,1,1,\cdots,1)$

It seems closely related to find a 'base change matrix'.

Moreover $e$ is eigenvector of $B(\gamma)$, indeed we have $B(\gamma)e=Ie+\gamma ee^{T}e=e+\gamma e n=(1+\gamma n)e$. So it seems that I have to find a basis of eigenvector but how can I do this here?

Comment: Do you know how to diagonalise matrices?

Comment: @Huy Yes but the next question in the paper I have is to prove that $B(\gamma)$ is symmetric definite positive so I was thinking that we don't need to diagonalise it because I need to say $B(\gamma)$ is symmetric real then diagonalizable..

Comment: You can see from your definition of $B(\gamma)$ that $B(\gamma)$ is symmetric, and then, from the spectral theorem, it follows that there is such an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors. Also, from the diagonal matrix in your post, you can read off the eigenvalues of $B(\gamma)$ and conclude that the matrix is also positive definite.

Comment: @Huy Hum in fact the question was **how** can we find such matrix so I just have to answer by the spectral theorem?

Comment: No, the spectral theorem only gives existence of such an eigenbasis. But you already know how to diagonalise matrices, and due to the spectral theorem, you will be able to choose the eigenvectors such that they are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an orthogonal matrix $V$ such that $V^Te=\|e\|_2e_1=\sqrt{n}e_1$, where $e_1=[1,0,\ldots,0]^T$ (take any orthogonal matrix $V$ with the first column equal to $e/\sqrt{n}$). Then
$$
V^T(I+\gamma e e^T)V=V^TV+\gamma (V^Te)(V^Te)^T=I+\gamma n e_1e_1^T
$$
is your diagonal matrix.

Comment: Can you explain what a Householder reflection is?

Comment: @Gato  given $a, b$ such that $|a| = |b|$, householder matrix is a an orthogonal matrix of the form $H = 2xx^T/x^Tx - I$ or $H = I - 2yy^T/y^Ty$ where $x = a + b, y = a -b$ so that $Ha = b$ and $Hb = a$